# What does で do at the end of the first sentence?

Tags: grammar

> 装備一式が未だギルドの支給品である自分には、笑ってしまうくらい不釣り合いな代物だとわかっているけど、一度は使ってみたいとそう思ってしまうわけ**で**。...欲しいなぁ。

I'm not sure how to interpret the で at the end of this sentence. Is there something being omitted here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I had to say, it's an omission of わけであって…… to leave the sentence hanging (cf. わけである for a full-stop). It really doesn't mean much.